# command line arguments in launch file

Tags: ros, launch-file, perception-pcl

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I am using pcd_to_pointcloud from perception_pcl and want to remap the output using a launch file.
The problem is that it requires a pcd file as a command line argument which I do not get to work using a launch file. Is there an easy way or should I issue a pull request for a modified node which can also read a pcd file path from a parameter.

Kai

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/55793/command-line-arguments-in-launch-file/) by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1554 on 2013-02-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Did you try it? This shouldn't be a problem in general. Pass the .pcd as `args` in the `<node>` tag and do the remapping within a `<remap>` tag in the `<node>`.

If it doesn't work, something is wrong. The ROS args should be consumed by `ros::init` and leave the .pcd as a param.

---

Originally posted by [dornhege](https://answers.ros.org/users/122/dornhege/) with karma: 31395 on 2013-02-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [kalectro](https://answers.ros.org/users/3904/kalectro/) on 2013-02-20**:
I did try it out, but it did not work. I just tried again and it worked. It turns out I did not specify the full path for the pcd file. Thanks a lot